# pip install package from Artifactory and install dependencies from PyPI

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, artifactory, python-poetry

I have a package that I am trying to install from Artifactory by running the following command

```
pip install package_name -i http://artifactory.XYZ.com/artifactory/api/pypi/XYZ-py-local/simple --trusted-host artifactory.XYZ.com
```

the package is downloaded fine. However when it comes to finding the dependencies it throws an exception because I don't have a PyPI remote repo in Artifactory.

Is it possible to point pip to PyPI for specific dependencies?

I'm using a `pyproject.toml` to store the requirements as I'm using poetry top handle dependencies and build the package.

Comment: Use `--extra-index-url` instead of `-i`.

Comment: In addition to `-i` I would say.

Answer (score 11):

Use `--extra-index-url` instead of `-i` like hoeffing said

or

create or edit your pip.conf file :

```
[global]
index-url = http://artifactory.XYZ.com/artifactory/api/pypi/XYZ-py-local/simple --trusted-host artifactory.XYZ.com
```

Comment: You can also edit your `pip.conf` file using the command `pip config set 'global.index-url' https://...`

Answer (score 3):

If anyone uses a requirements.txt file, it's possible to include inside the file.

```
--index-url http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-local/simple
PyYAML==3.11
argparse==1.2.1
frog-bar==0.2
frog-fu==0.2a
nltk==2.0.4
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Contact your Artifactory admin to add a virtual repository that will include your local repository and a remote.

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Virtual+Repositories